# Disable current time in Vue2 Timepicker

Tags: vuejs2

I'm using Vue2 timepicker
Demo : https://github.com/phoenixwong/vue2-timepicker/blob/master/README.md

How can I disable all times before the current time in the time picker?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:hour-range` and `:minute-range` you can check the details here: https://phoenixwong.github.io/vue2-timepicker/#hourRange
Those props accept array of hour, if you nest an array inside of it then it will be a range, which I will use for this type of problem.

If you need to update the disabled hour/minute on real time each second, you might need to implement `setInterval` or something similar.

Here's the Vue HTML:

```html
<vue-timepicker :hour-range="enabledHours" :minute-range="enabledMinutes"></vue-timepicker>
```

We can utilize `computed` for writing the `enabledHours` and `enabledMinutes`

something like this:

```js
computed: {
  enabledHours(){
    const currentHour = new Date().getHours();
    return [ [ currentHour, 23 ] ];
  }, 
  enabledMinutes(){
    const currentMinute = new Date().getMinutes();
    return [ [ currentMinute, 59 ] ];
  }  
}
```

You can also add `:second-range` if you need to and the format would be the same with `:hour-range` and `:minute-range`